# How to convert key - value pair in to array of same key-value pairs

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb

I am working on e-commerce site using nextjs, express, mongoose, nodejs. User has selected items to order. When he wants to view his list, I call the list of items from userSchema. It is list of ordered items which I get in the below given format:

```
myList: {
  createdAt: 2021-03-19T12:03:41.989Z,
  isPaid: false,
  isDelivered: false,
  _id: 605493f4bd3f98bb9bd5366c,
  menuId: 3,
  userId: 6006018031a53c2d47e01d93,
  itemName: 'Masala Khichdi',
  itemPrice: 15,
  itemSize: 64,
  qtty: 2,
  itemPic: '/images/food-menu-3@2X.png',
  summary: '+918 372 574',
  __v: 0
},{
  createdAt: 2021-03-19T12:22:23.579Z,
  isPaid: false,
  isDelivered: false,
  _id: 6054c60667a9c2bc7e2522ce,
  menuId: 4,
  userId: 6006018031a53c2d47e01d93,
  itemName: 'Food Menu 4',
  itemPrice: 12,
  itemSize: 32,
  qtty: 1,
  itemPic: '/images/food-menu-4@2X.png',
  summary: '+123 456 789',
  __v: 0
},{
  createdAt: 2021-03-19T12:22:23.579Z,
  isPaid: false,
  isDelivered: false,
  _id: 6054c85467a9c2bc7e2522cf,
  menuId: 3,
  userId: 6006018031a53c2d47e01d93,
  itemName: 'Masala Khichdi',
  itemPrice: 11,
  itemSize: 32,
  qtty: 2,
  itemPic: '/images/food-menu-3@2X.png',
  summary: '+918 372 574',
  __v: 0
}
```

To process further I need to convert the same list to an array as shown below:

```
myList: [{
  createdAt: 2021-03-19T12:03:41.989Z,
  isPaid: false,
  isDelivered: false,
  _id: 605493f4bd3f98bb9bd5366c,
  menuId: 3,
  userId: 6006018031a53c2d47e01d93,
  itemName: 'Masala Khichdi',
  itemPrice: 15,
  itemSize: 64,
  qtty: 2,
  itemPic: '/images/food-menu-3@2X.png',
  summary: '+918 372 574',
  __v: 0
},{
  createdAt: 2021-03-19T12:22:23.579Z,
  isPaid: false,
  isDelivered: false,
  _id: 6054c60667a9c2bc7e2522ce,
  menuId: 4,
  userId: 6006018031a53c2d47e01d93,
  itemName: 'Food Menu 4',
  itemPrice: 12,
  itemSize: 32,
  qtty: 1,
  itemPic: '/images/food-menu-4@2X.png',
  summary: '+123 456 789',
  __v: 0
},{
  createdAt: 2021-03-19T12:22:23.579Z,
  isPaid: false,
  isDelivered: false,
  _id: 6054c85467a9c2bc7e2522cf,
  menuId: 3,
  userId: 6006018031a53c2d47e01d93,
  itemName: 'Masala Khichdi',
  itemPrice: 11,
  itemSize: 32,
  qtty: 2,
  itemPic: '/images/food-menu-3@2X.png',
  summary: '+918 372 574',
  __v: 0
} ]
```

How to do this in backend using nodejs

Comment: what have you tried? please add your try in your question. you can use aggregate() function with [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) stage to group all items in array

Answer (score -1):

what is your mongoose query? if you are retrieving data according to userId.
Add .toArray() method in your query.